# Cannot access parent's protected method in Java

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have this problem:

A java class that contains an inner class. The inner class (`Authenticator`) extends the `javax.mail.Authenticator` (note the same name for both class and subclass).

The problem is that I can't access the protected method `getPasswordAuthentication` unless the inner class has the same name as the extended class (I mean `Authenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator`). 
If I write `private class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator` then I can't access anymore the protected `getPasswordAuthentication`.
See code below:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.RecipientType;

public class MailWithPasswordAuthentication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {
        new MailWithPasswordAuthentication().run();
    }

    private void run() throws MessagingException {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(getSession());

        message.addRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("to@example.com"));
        message.addFrom(new InternetAddress[] { new InternetAddress("from@example.com") });

        message.setSubject("the subject");
        message.setContent("the body", "text/plain");

        Transport.send(message);
    }

    private Session getSession() {
        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.submitter", authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication().getUserName());
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "mail.example.com");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "25");

        return Session.getInstance(properties, authenticator);
    }

    private class Authenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
        private PasswordAuthentication authentication;

        public Authenticator() {
            String username = "auth-user";
            String password = "auth-password";
            authentication = new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }

        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return authentication;
        }
    }
}
```

thankx,
A

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: The name of the class will not determine the access level of a method.

Comment: I agree, the name of the class will not determine the access level of a method. This is why I'm asking this question. Please see my comments below. The error is: The method getPasswordAuthentication() from the type Authenticator is not visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rename your Authenticator class to SMTPAuthenticator, you should also change the line:

```
Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();
```

to

```
SMTPAuthenticator authenticator = new SMTPAuthenticator();
```

The reason you get the error is that only the `SMTPAuthenticator` class contains the `getPasswordAuthentication()` method, not the base `Authenticator` class

Comment: This could be a very good answer, interested to see what the OP's actual error is.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, I should use SMTPAuthenticator authenticator = new SMTPAuthenticator() instead of Authenticator authenticator = new SMTPAuthenticator(). I confused with interface where you can use "interface = new implementation". Thank you

Comment: So, with Authenticator authenticator = new SMTPAuthenticator()I get this error which is correct: "The method getPasswordAuthentication() from the type Authenticator is not visible"

Comment: @AdrianT I hope my edit clarifies the reason you got the error

Comment: Yes, thanks again...it was not an implementation of an interface as I thought but an extension of another class.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access `Authenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticatore` then you should be able to access `class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator`. If not then your observation is wrong .